# Что такое Command-line тулы?

Tags: python, linux, консоль

Я новичок и хочу разобраться.
Искал в интернете. Где-то пишут, что это связанно с командой строкой линукс, где-то пишут, что это отдельные самописные программы для взаимодействия с ОС.
Может кто-нибудь знающий разъяснить что это?

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/command-line-for-beginners#1-overview

Comment: Не обязательно "самописная". Очень много таких утилит фактически являются частью ОС. Command-line - это просто способ взаимодействия, т.е. взаимодействие идет через командную строку, а не через графический интерфейс. Графический интерфейс не всегда нужен, на самом деле.

Answer (score 0):

`ComandLine tools` -  это средство взаимодействия с устройством или компьютерной программой с помощью команд от пользователя или клиента и ответов от устройства или программы. Они имеют интерфейс, набор команд. Они могут быть написаны для разных операционных систем, пишутся такие команды на `shell`, `powershell`, `ruby`, `swift`, `python` и т.д, в зависимости от ОС.